# Database design: nested tables

Tags: database, database-design, database-relations

I am working on creating a database schema for recipes cost management , and I ran into a problem I do not know how to best solve.

I have a table ingredients (Id_ingedients, Name_ingredients, ....)
I have a table recipe (Id_recipe, Name_recipe, Type_recipe, ....)

The Type_recipe is: Finished_recipe or Sub_recipe

I have a transition table ingredients_recipe (Id_ingredients, Id_recipe)

Now my problem: The recipe could contain ingredients (easy) but also recipe with the Sub-recipe type !! And also recipe with Sub_recipe type can contain ingredients but also sub_recipe.

I found a solution for one degre Sub_recipe:

I create a table Sub_recipe (Id_sub_recipe, Subrecipe name, ...)
and a intermediate table ingedients_sub_recipe(Id_sub_recipe,id_ingredients)
and a table sub_recipe_recipe(id_recipe,id_sub_recipe) to link recipe and sub_recipe

But this schema don't work if this sub_recipe contain a other sub_recipe !!

I think I'm wrong on the database design, could you help me to design my database schema.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need only 3 tables:

1. ingredients - ingredient_id, ingredient_name, ....
2. recipes - recipe_id, recipe_name, .... (no need for a type since each recipe can behave like sub-recipe when used in a bigger dish)
3. connections - parent_recipe_id, child_recipe_id, child_ingredient_id

For example, if your dish is cooked with recipe 1:

- recipe 1 contains ingredients A and B + recipe 2 + recipe 3
- recipe 2 contains ingredients C, D and E
- recipe 3 contains ingredient F + recipe 4
- recipe 4 contains recipe 5 + recipe 6 but no ingredients by itself
- recipe 5 contains ingredients G and H
- recipe 6 contains ingredients K and L

so your transition table (CONNECTIONS) will look like this

```
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| Parent_recipe_id | Child_recipe_id | Child_ingredient_id |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        1         |      NULL       |          1          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        1         |      NULL       |          2          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        1         |        2        |        NULL         |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        1         |        3        |        NULL         |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        2         |      NULL       |          3          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        2         |      NULL       |          4          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        2         |      NULL       |          5          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        3         |      NULL       |          6          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        3         |        4        |        NULL         |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        4         |        5        |        NULL         |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        4         |        6        |        NULL         |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        5         |      NULL       |          7          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        5         |      NULL       |          8          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        6         |      NULL       |          9          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|        6         |      NULL       |         10          |
+------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```